# How to implement this bubble piechart?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

I need to implement this:

[image: screenshot]

Honestly I don't have any idea how to google this. I'm looking for a Vue/Nuxt solution or any hints in general on how to implement this.

**EDIT:** Sorry for bad question i guess. I was not asking for tutorial on how to do circle. I needed to do different charts using API. For anyone else looking for this i found Bubble Cloud Chart in [vue-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-graph)

Comment: In css, border-style: 1px solid black; border-radius:50%; width:100px; height:100px; something like this

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a how-to/place to ask for tutorials. You may need to look for graph/chart libraries. Try some words like that in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Using simple CSS:

```css
#pie {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #F3F3F4;
  
  
  /* Center text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="pie">
  <p>32%</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if I totally agree with the answer, IMO the OP wants something simple to use where he could provide an array with some values and get the whole size/position done and not code something by himself.